# Access and bind data outside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat which repeats a bunch of products in a dropdown.

On hover over these guys, I want to bounce the image that I'm hovering into a container outside of the dropdown.

**MARKUP:**

```
<div class="quick-view-filters-container" ng-controller="setZoomDrop">
    <!-- zoomed image container from ng-repeat below -->
    <div class="product--shade__image-zoom--container">
        <img class="ng-hide" ng-show="zoom=1" image="option.product" step="1" always="1" />
    </div>
    <!-- dropdown -->
    <div class="product-select-shades-container" ng-repeat="attribute in attributes | onlyAttrsWithManyOptions | orderBy:$parent.$parent.$parent.configurableOrder">
        <h4>Products:</h4>
        <div class="product--options_list">
            <div ng-repeat="option in attribute.options" class="product--option_item" ng-if="option.product">
                <span class="product--shade__image ">
                      <!-- image -->
                      <img class="{{:: attribute.code == 'lamp_colour_config' ? 'zoomed' : ''}}" image="option.product" step="1" ng-mouseenter="setZoom(1)" ng-mouseleave="setZoom(0)" always="1" />
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
window.app.controller('setZoomDrop', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    var zoom = null;

    $scope.setZoom = function(number) {
        $scope.zoom = number;

    };
}]);
```

**Workings:**

- You can see in the markup that I am setting a variable to 1 or 0 dependable on whether a product in the dropdown is hovered over.
  This I have tried to use in the zoomed image container.
- option.product in the zoomed image container will not work as I don't know how to pull out the active image from the ng-repeat.

Comment: It might help if you created a embedded example. A couple things jump out at me... `var zoom = null;` then `$scope.zoom = number` and that is a terrible variable name (especially on the scope and not the controller) so where is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your setZoom function, instead of passing a number pass the option object if mouseenter or null if mouseleave:

```
$scope.curOpt = null;
$scope.setZoom = function(option) {
   $scope.curOpt = option;
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<img ng-show="curOpt" image="curOpt.product" step="1" always="1" />
```

Comment: Not sure you would want to use ng-show here as the image tag will be there just display:none I would recoment ng-if. Keeps the DOM clean

Comment: - Agreed, Jackie. ps. Little hard to throw up working example.
- Tanenbring - what of the ng-mouseleave and ng-mouseout though? Like this?
ng-mouseenter="setZoom(option)" ng-mouseleave="setZoom(null)"